# DataTable Server side sort date by Year>Month>Day

Tags: sorting, datatable

It there a way to sort date by `Year -> Month -> Day` i tried to do `"order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],` It works fine but how can I do it like `Year -> Month -> Day`

```
var lead_birth_dt = $('#lead-birthday-table').DataTable({
                 processing: true,
                 language: {
                    processing: '<div class="loading-chart" style="background: #ececec00l; margin-bottom: 10px;"><img src="{{asset('assets/images/chart-loading.webp')}}"></div>',
                 },
                 serverSide: true,
                 select: true,
                 responsive: true,
                 "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
                 ajax: '{{ url("/date") }}',         
                 columns: [ 
                     { data: 'birthdate', name: 'birthdate', className: 'text-center',
                        render: function(data){
                            return ( moment(data, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('ll') );
                        },
                     },                           
                 ],
             });
```

E.g data
[image]